# Слайдер дублирует первую картинку

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Слайдер выводит картинки "первая-первая-вторая-третья" вместо "первая-вторая-третья-четвертая". Не получается исправить.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width: 550px; margin: 100px auto">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>

            <?php
            $data = [
                    '2ecc71',
                    '455678',
                    'b70e09',
                    'b6b70a',
                    '96878f',
                    '000000'
            ];
            ?>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <?php
                    $cnt = 0;
                    foreach ($data as $value) {
                        if ($value) {
                        $cnt++;
                            if ($cnt == 4) break;
                            if ($cnt == 1) { ?>
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200/<?= $value ?>" style="width: 400px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto">
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200/<?= $value ?>" style="width: 400px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto">
                                </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
            </div>

            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: для начала отключите формирование слайдера на js и посмотрите что у вас пых выводит

Comment: всё, получилось